# How can I stop IE7-8 from caching the display of this jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using the function below to show a random quote in #quotescontainer each time there is a tab change in jQuery Tabs UI. Works fine in everything except IE7-8 (of course).

What happens in IE7-8 is the first quote is displayed and a second, random quote appears in #quotescontainer right below the first quote. In all other browsers, only one quote shows and it rotates on tab change. So IE is grabbing the first quote in div.quote from quotes.html, showing it and also showing a random quote underneath the first quote.

What can I try to force IE to correctly swap the quotes? And not get 'stuck" on the first quote?

Is this a cache prooblem? Or a problem with the function always reading quote1 and appending quote2 below it?

I'm not using caching in .htaccess. I've tried adding `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` in the function with no luck.

**6/01/11 fix;** issue was some html inside the `<div class="quote">quote text</div>` in quotes.html. Somehow, that was breaking IE7-8.

**jsfiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/YAEe5/28/

**My function:** *with help from Matthew Ratzloff below*

```
    select: function(event, ui) {

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.pow(2, 32) - 1));
  $('div#quotescontainer').load('http://mydomain.com/quotes.html?' + random, function() {
    var quotes = $(this).find('div.quote');
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    quotes.hide().eq(index).fadeIn();
  });
```

**quotes are displayed** on the page in `#quotescontainer`

**quotes.html** contains this:

```
<div class="quote">Quote1</div>
<div class="quote">Quote2</div>
<div class="quote">Quote3</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a complete, tested, working example of what you want to do.  You should be able to pull everything inside of the `$(document).ready` function into your `select` handler.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.pow(2, 32) - 1));
  $('div#quotescontainer').load('quotes.html?' + random, function() {
    var quotes = $(this).find('div.quote');
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    quotes.hide().eq(index).fadeIn();
  });
});
</script>
<div id="quotescontainer"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, but something in it breaks the tabs init. All I get is the #hash in the browser and no tabs are clickable.

Comment: Probably a JavaScript error.  Hard to tell without the output from the console, though.

Comment: Good idea to check the console. The error is `Can't find variable: $quotes` I added the complete run of functions I'm working with above.

Comment: OK, I finally stopped being lazy and created a single-page example of working code.  I know this works.

Comment: Appreciate the help. That should work, but there's something else in my combined function that still shows two quotes. But I also tried it standalone in its own doc ready with no luck. Puzzle. Is there a way to check for the two divs `<div class="quote">` and if there are two, set the first to `display:none`? Maybe that's an ugly way around it.

Comment: @songdogtech, I'm sorry, I can't reproduce the error you're having.  I've updated your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/YAEe5/41/) so the example works (it didn't before due to same-origin policy) and put my code example on my own site.  I've tested both of these in Internet Explorer 7 on a Windows test box and no matter what I do I cannot replicate the issue you seem to be having.  If you can't get this to work I recommend recreating your quotes.html page as quotes.json, pulling in an array of quotes, and setting just the randomly-selected quote you want in div#quotescontainer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: That might be the only way to get it to work, but I don't really want to load all the quotes into the page and then select from them. Thanks for your help. I may just change the whole thing I'm trying to do. Arg.

Comment: There's no difference.  One is loading them all into the DOM and hiding all but one, the other is loading them all into JavaScript and showing one.  If you don't want to load the entire thing you're going to have to write something in a server-side language like Ruby that outputs one quote at a time.

Comment: Ah-hah. Finally figured out what's going on. In my quotes.html file, I have other html inside of each `<div class="quote">quote text</div>`, i.e. `<span>` and escaped html, like `&ldquo;`, etc. And some of that broke IE. So I was able to move that out of the div.

Answer (score 1):

If `no-cache`  or other caching options dont work , you can try

```
$('div#quotescontainer').html('')
```

after this  call your function and load

```
$('div#quotescontainer').load('http://mydomain.com/quotes.html',function
```

Comment: Good idea; I use something like that to clear other functions on document ready, but no luck with it for the quotes function.

Answer (score 0):

Append a random number to the end of that URL: http://mydomain.com/quotes.html?rand=439786

It'll keep your browser from caching it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code problem, not the browser problem.

You code doesn't need data caching. So, stop using it. To do it from your code, just stop using the HTTP GET command (which is used by the .load() function). Load your html, json, script or whatever data your URL mydomain.com/quotes.html? sends back with global $.post() function which uses HTTP POST command. Post data doesn't get cached. You can do it in page's load event by assigning the returned data to a global var and then sending it to your div element. Or something like that.

Or to solve it from your client, open Internet Options of IE. In the Browsing History section (I'm using IE9 right now) click button Settings. In the dialog, select "Every time I visit the page" instead of default "Automatically". Then clear browser's cache (Ctrl+Shift+Delete) and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to load all quotes from quotes.html everytime you switch a tab? I'd load the quotes 'on docuemnt ready' make all hidden and perform only the selection on a tab select. Example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/YAEe5/40/

Tested on IE8 and in compat mode, seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, and that is a way to get it to work, but I don't want to load 5K of text into the page and then select from it.